# Why does the compiler complain with illegal start of expression error message?

Tags: java, static, expression

This code looks through several files to find the popularity and meaning of whatever name you type in. The class constants that have errors are for a graph I have yet to make within the class. They are not being used right now, but will be soon.

I'm getting these errors:

```
BabyNames.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   ^
BabyNames.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
          ^
BabyNames.java:8: error: ';' expected
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
                ^
BabyNames.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   ^
BabyNames.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
          ^ 
BabyNames.java:9: error: ';' expected
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
                ^
BabyNames.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 
   ^
BabyNames.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 
          ^
BabyNames.java:10: error: ';' expected
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30;
```

I think I have all the correct semi colons here, but I'm not sure what's going on 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//import java.lang.*;

public class BabyNames{ //ADD COMMENTS
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780,560);
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      Scanner nameFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      Scanner meaningsFile = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      Scanner nameFile2 = new Scanner(new File("names2.txt"));
      intro();
      //nameToLowerCase(console);
      if(STARTINGYEAR = 1890){
      findingStatistics(console,nameFile);
      }
      else{
      findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);       
      drawGraph(g);
   }



   public static void intro(){
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");
      System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
      System.out.println("since 1890" );
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Name: ");
      }

   public static String nameToLowerCase(Scanner console, Scanner data){   
      String originalName = console.next();
      String name = "" ;
      int lengthOfName = originalName.length();
      String beginingOfName = originalName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String endOfName = originalName.substring(1,lengthOfName).toLowerCase();
      name = beginingOfName + endOfName;
      return name;
   }
   public static String findingStatistics(Scanner console, Scanner data){
      String nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);
      boolean goesThroughOnce = false; //
      String statistics = "";
      String currWord = "";
      String currLine = "";
      while (data.hasNext() && goesThroughOnce == false){ 
         currLine = data.nextLine();
         Scanner lineBeingRead = new Scanner(currLine); //make other scanners?? for each file
         currWord = lineBeingRead.next(); //

         if (currWord.equals(nameFinal) || currWord.equals(nameFinal.toUpperCase())){   //         
            statistics = currLine;
            goesThroughOnce = true;
            System.out.println(statistics);
        }
        else{
        }
   }
   return statistics;
}
```

Comment: `public` isn't a valid attribute for a method-local variable, nor is `static`.

Answer (score 3):

These are called constants in Java and they should be defined in the class itself, not in its main method.

```
public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
.....
```

Now, if you remove the `public static`, you can keep them in your main method but seems that's not what you intended. Also, this will make it impossible to use them in other methods as they will become local final variables of the main method.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors:

1. move static members out of the main method
2. DrawingPanel needs to be imported (in case its not in the same package)
3. Either change params of

   nameToLowerCase(Scanner console, Scanner data)

to

```
nameToLowerCase(Scanner console)
```

or add the seconds parameter to its call

```
String nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);
```

To avoid such mistakes i recommend to use an ide like eclipse or intellij.

Comment: if it is in the same package, you don't need to. If not write this at the beginning of your java file: "import PACKAGE_PATH_TO_DRAWING_PANEL.DrawingPanel"

Comment: BabyNames.java:1: error: package PACKAGE_PATH_TO_DRAWING_PANEL does not exist

Comment: I thought I did import drawing panel so I don't understand why graphics won't work

Comment: "PACKAGE_PATH_TO_DRAWING_PANEL" is a place holder for you to insert the correct package name, I don't know where you have got that package ;-).

Comment: I'm confused, what's the name of the package I need to import?

Comment: I figured it out, it's java.awt.*

Answer (score 0):

Move your static members outside the main method :

```
public class BabyNames
{
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780,560);
       Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
       Scanner nameFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
       Scanner meaningsFile = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
       Scanner nameFile2 = new Scanner(new File("names2.txt"));
       intro();
       //nameToLowerCase(console);
       if(STARTINGYEAR = 1890){
           findingStatistics(console,nameFile);
       } else {
           findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);       
           drawGraph(g);
       }
   }
```

And indent your code, which would help you locate missing braces (as in the end of your main method).

Comment: Also, there's a missing brace to close the `main` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza-there's a missing brace`(})`, not a `;`!

Comment: There's a missing `}` not a missing semicolon, I think.

Comment: Fast typing, confused words, but all of you get the idea.